# Easy Hosting Control Panel creates multiple backup

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

I have a server that's running Ubuntu 16.04. and apparently Easy Hosting Control Panel keeps on creating multiple back-ups like 50 times a day which fills the 50 gb disk space and it's causing the server to crash.

The backup is creating multiple directories named Apache2.backupbyehcp inside /etc directory.

I've tried deleting the backups one by one and after a day there it is again.

I want to disable or limit the backups created.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a screen shot of the backup directories that are being created:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by:
Ehcp trying to recover webserver config, each time it detects that the webserver config is broken or webserver not responding.

This may result in such unexpected/unwanted behaviour.

What to do:
1st, check the problem in webserver configs, like, `tail -f /var/log/ehcp.log`
so that you can understand what is going wrong.
This is sometime caused by incorrect webserver custom configurations by admin or reseller. You may disable custom webserver configs via ehcp gui-> options.

(I strongly suggest finding the cause of this.)

If everything regarding the webserver is okay, but you just need to disable this backup, 
open `install_lib.php` in `ehcp` dir, search for `backupbyehcp` and disable that line.

Hope this helps.